# Magento 2 : Add Js to cart after grand total load

Tags: javascript, magento, magento2

I need to load my Js after grand-total.html because I would like to recover the value of the total amount.

I try to launch my Javascript with

```
$(window).load(function () {
...
}
```

but grand-total.html loads after the page loads.

I try to add in layout "chackout_cart_index.xml" like that :

```
<referenceBlock name="checkout.cart.totals">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="block-totals" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="grand-total" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="gtm" xsi:type="string">MyModule_GoogleTagManager/js/gtmCart</item>
                                    </item>
                                </item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
```

but my Js file don't load on my website

Do you have an idea for launch my js after grand-total.html ?